# discord.py command doesn't work when added to an event listener

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = 'my token lol'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

        
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(my channel id)
    await channel.send(f'Bravo! Ca marche. Du champagne, {ctx.author.mention} ?')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

This code works just fine. I also wanted the bot to repeat what you say, so I plugged a new snippet of code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content != "!hello":
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

This also works fine. It repeats what you say. But when I tried the command, it didn't work anymore.
Could someone please explain me why?

Full code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = 'my token lol'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content != "!hello":
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(my channel id)
    await channel.send(f'Bravo! Ca marche. Du champagne, {ctx.author.mention} ?')
client.run(TOKEN)
```